# How long does azure cdn live before updating

Tags: azure, cdn, ttl

I am using the windows Azure CDN, 
And not like Amazon's one cannot configure any TTL regarding the files,

I was wondering if there is any official document microsoft had regarding to the Time-to-live of the cdn content until it is being update ?

Or does anyone know this at all...

Here is a document about the cdn from microsoft, they mention the TTL but not its size :

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/cdn/

Answer (score 2):

If you pull from an Azure blob service, the time to live is governed by the [*x-ms-blob-cache-control* property that you set on each blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680306.aspx).

If you pull from an Azure cloud service or custom domain, then the time to live is governed by the [HTTP `Cache-Control` response header that the origin server sends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680299.aspx).

Comment: Regarding cloud services, is there a default value for that cahce-control ? what if i dont define it ?

Comment: Then you need to read RFC 2616 and talk to your web developer.

Answer (score -1):

just wanted to give you the link for all the How To Manage related to the Windows Azure CDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg680305.aspx

this link will help you with all the related issues of the Windows Azure CDN

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please provide content **here** and then link elsewhere for more details.